# php - Woocommerce - users can buy only one product

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, product

for a project I want to create a webshop that offers six products.
A user can then go to the site and choose only one of the six products.
Once the product is selected, the user is immediately forwarded to the checkout and should only be able to order by mail.
once the order has been completed, the user should no longer be able to order.
That means, the email address should be saved and should be recognized when the user tries to order again.

Is there a plugin or code to help me?

The page is already up and I just need a solution for the checkout.

Comment: Maybe you should go for 1 product with 6 variations...

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here, give this a go. It will redirect your customers directly to the checkout and only one product can be purchased at a time. It won't help with preventing a user ordering twice but its a start, Good Luck!

/*Only Allow One Product In Cart*/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10, 3);
function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id )
{
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
// Do nothing with the data and return
return $cart_item_data;
}
```

/* Bypass Cart Page */

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 
'themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect');
function themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect() {
global $woocommerce;
$checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
return $checkout_url;
}
```

​